# Is it possible to assign array values at compile-time through constexpr functions?

Tags: c++, constexpr, compile-time

I am fairly new to templates and compile-time functions, and I am currently trying to write a basic entity-component-system (ECS) that will allow me to store generic types (components) in containers. I want functionality to be able to setup my containers at compile-time, and run-time. There are some instances in my application where I know for certain which components will always persist for an entity so I want to be able to set these up and reserve the slots at compile-time. There are then occasions where components will need to be removed/added at runtime dynamically.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct ComponentArray {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr const T& AddComponent(const uint64_t entity, Args &&... args) const
    {
        //T component{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }; //i want to be able to do something like this..
        //m_components[0] = component; //create the component and give it a slot, but this is const
        return m_components[0];
    }

    std::array<T, N>    m_components = {};
    std::array<T, N>    m_entityIds = {};
    uint32_t            m_used = 0;
};

template <uint64_t entityId, typename Component, typename ... Args>
constexpr const Component& AddComponentCT(Args&&... args)
{
    constexpr uint64_t componentHash = GetHashForString(ComponentTypeInfo<Component>::m_name, ComponentTypeInfo<Component>::m_nameLength);
    constexpr uint64_t storageHash = ComponentStorageMapping<componentHash>::m_hash;
    static_assert(storageHash == componentHash);

    constexpr const auto& componentStorage = ComponentStorageMapping<componentHash>::m_componentStorage;

    constexpr const Component& rComponent = componentStorage.AddComponent(entityId /*std::forward<Args>(args)...*/);

    return rComponent;
}


constexpr const TransformComponent transform = AddComponentCT<ENTITY_ID, TransformComponent>(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
```

This seems to work, and when I hover over `transform`, I can see what is returned but obviously incorrect values as I can't construct the type using the arguments in the const function.
[image]

I have also tried to remove some of the const from the variables but then it complains that things aren't const or can't be evaluated.

I am looking to create a type of `Component`, with the arguments provided and then find a free slot in `m_components` to store it. Is something like this possible at compile-time? If anyone has suggestions on how I could achieve what I want, or improve the solution it would be much appreciated. There is some macro code that I haven't included here which generates the classes like `ComponentStorageMapping`, `ComponentTypeInfo` and `m_componentStorage`

---

Below is a more simplified/generic version as requested in the comments

```
struct A
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct B
{
    int i, j, k;
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct C {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr const T& AddToArray(Args &&... args) const
    {
        //T element{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }; //i want to be able to do something like this..
        //m_array[0] = element; //create the component and give it a slot, but this is const
        return m_array[0];
    }

    std::array<T, N>    m_array = {};
};


template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr const T& AddElement(Args&&... args)
{
    constexpr const T& element = C<T, 50>::AddToArray(/*std::forward<Args>(args)...*/);

    return element;
}


constexpr const A& someArrayElement = AddElement<A>(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f); //this would point to C<A,50>::m_array[0], fully constructed
constexpr const A& someArrayElement2 = AddElement<A>(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f); //this would point to C<A,50>::m_array[1], fully constructed

constexpr const B& someArrayElement3 = AddElement<B>(1, 1, 1); //this would point to C<B,50>::m_array[0], fully constructed
constexpr const B& someArrayElement4 = AddElement<B>(2, 2, 2); //this would point to C<B,50>::m_array[1], fully constructed
```

For the record, I created another post (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176301/how-can-i-create-a-templated-function-to-add-components-to-their-necessary-conta) before this one to see how I would approach this situation and didn't receive many suggestions so I just tried to do it myself and this is the problem I have encountered. There is another framework achieving what I'm trying to do in some way, but I don't quite understand what they're doing as it's all templates. Links to the framework are in the other post.

Comment: Can you simplify the example?  Right now, you are showing a lot of irrelevant details (e.g., components, transform, hash, etc.).  Remove these and keep a generic class like `C` with one single array member.  If anything is not relevant to the problem, leave it out.

Comment: @L.F. not a problem, I'll keep that in mind for future reference. I just thought a little context might help but you're right, probably didn't help in this case. I have added another snippet to my post which strips out most of the unnecessary code.

Comment: Can you still simplify what exactly you're asking? Because well, constructing a whatever-thing that is inside an array with minimal copying, and from a constant expression as well is kinda trivial (`std::array::operator[]` returns a reference, so it's basically "emplace", and as long as your T has a `constexpr` constructor you're good to go). `constexpr`-initializing a whole array zero-overhead is trivial, too. But finding an empty slot at runtime and then inserting _something_, and that being `constexpr` sounds like it is pretty much impossible (how should that work?).

Comment: @Damon I'm not really sure how to simplify it further or whether what I'm asking is even possible but I'm sure there's some solution that can achieve something similar. So the `m_array` is zero initialized, and I can construct my compile-time objects `A` and `B`, but in my example `AddToArray`, I want to construct an object of `T` and insert it into a slot in `m_array`, and then return that slot. However I can't do that because the function is const and `m_array` can't be modified.

Comment: For the record, I created another post (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176301/how-can-i-create-a-templated-function-to-add-components-to-their-necessary-conta) before this one to see how I would approach this situation and didn't receive many suggestions so I just tried to do it myself and this is the problem I have encountered. There is another framework achieving what I'm trying to do in some way, but I don't quite understand what they're doing as it's all templates. Links to the framework are in the other post.

Comment: Well, whatever combination of template helper functions (with types, value template params, or forwarding varags) and assigning to a `std::array` element [certainly works trivially, as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/Dn3bGa) as long as the type is assignable. No matter how you call it. Only just, getting it all `constexpr` when it is by all means not `constexpr` (modification at runtime!) will prove "difficult". I mean, how can you leave the array constant when you're obviously modifying it? But that's quite obvious(?), hence my problem understanding the question.

Comment: @Damon yes it's being modified, but with compile-time values. It's not like they're run-time values where they are unknown at compile-time. max66 posted an answer suggesting that the array just gets constructed with the types I want in there, rather than be zero initialized and attempting to add them after and I think that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Strip the `={}` then, if you want to skip the initialization, since you explicitly do an aggregate initialization there, which (braces being empty) _is_ zero-initialization (compare the two. code is not identical: https://godbolt.org/z/ON05S-). That still doesn't make the assignment `constexpr` of course (but this isn't possible at all, in my opinion).Constructing in-place (dynamically, at runtime, from constant data) is as constant as you can get with something that isn't const by nature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible what do you want.

See what you have written for `AddToArray()`

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr const T& AddToArray(Args &&... args) const
{
    //T element{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }; //i want to be able to do something like this..
    //m_array[0] = element; //create the component and give it a slot, but this is const
    // .......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return m_array[0];
}
```

Do you want a `constexpr` method, that is also `const`, that add a component in a member of the class/struct.

And obviously you can't use it as follows

```
constexpr const A& someArrayElement = AddElement<A>(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
constexpr const A& someArrayElement2 = AddElement<A>(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
```

Yuo can't call `AddElement()` without an object of its type.

You should start with a `constexpr` object of type `C`

```
constexpr C<A, 50u>  ca;
```

and then use it to call `AddElement()`

```
constexpr const A& someArrayElement = ca.AddElement<A>(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
constexpr const A& someArrayElement2 = ca.AddElement<A>(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
// ....................................^^^
```

but if `ca` is `constexpr` you can't add elements in it and if `ca` isn't `constexpr` you can't use the result of `AddElement()` to initialize the value of a `constexpr` variable.

The only way to I see to solve this problem is initialize the `ca` object with all elements; something as

```
constexpr C<A, 50u>  ca { A{5.0f, 5.0f, 5,0f}, A{10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f} /* etc ... */ };
```

and then extract the reference to the components

```
constexpr A & someArrayElement  = ca.GetElement(0);
constexpr A & someArrayElement2 = ca.GetElement(1);
```